# Unwrapping a promise to get at data inside

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

My Spring Boot back-end sends responses to front-end requests like this:

```js
{
    "timestamp":[2022,6,16],
    "status":"OK",
    "data": {
                "products": [{"product1":"Rake"},{"product2":"Hammer"},...]
            }
    
}
```

How do I unwrap this response so that I can store the value of "products" (the products array) in the `data` variable below and display it in my table (I'm using Material btw)?

```js
/**
 * Data source for the ProductTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class ProductTableDataSource extends DataSource<ProductTableItem> {

  data: ProductTableItem[] = [];
  paginator: MatPaginator | undefined;
  sort: MatSort | undefined;
  errorMessage: string = '';

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    super();
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
      next: products => this.data = products,
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }
```

You can see that the above won't work because I am sending the whole response (including the timestamp and status fields) to the `data` variable which only expects an array like this: `[{"product1":"Rake"},{"product2":"Hammer"},...]`.

Here is my service class:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productUrl = 'back-end URL';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getProducts(): Observable<ProductTableItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<ProductTableItem[]>(this.productUrl).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Comment: `.get<ProductTableItem[]>` is a lie - you _don't_ expect the response body to be an array, according to your first sample. If you give the compiler accurate information it can guide you through the rest.

Comment: So here's what I'm thinking I should do (tell me if I'm off track): 1. Create an Interface of type `Response` which would have members `timestamp: number[]`, `status: string`, `data: any`. 2. Change `.get<ProductTable[]>` to `.get<Response>`. So let's say I do that, I assume my Observable will change too? From `Observable<ProductTableItem[]>` to `Observable<Response>`? Where do I put the logic to get at the `data` member which holds the array I want? I assume it won't be in the `getProducts()` method but in the place where I subscribe to my Observable - right?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Whether you expose the Response or keep the current interface is up to you (but I'd recommend more towards the latter, the whole point of the service is an _abstraction layer_ that means the rest of your app doesn't have to know the details of the request and response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service doesn't return `ProductTableItem` but the server response. Create two models:

```
export class ProductData {
  products?: ProductTableItem[]
}
```

and

```
export class ServerResponse<T> {
  timestamp: any;
  status: string;
  data: T;
}
```

Now in your service:

```
getProducts(): Observable<ServerResponse<ProductData>> {
  return this.http.get<ServerResponse<ProductData>>(this.productUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

and in your component:

```
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe({
    next: (response : ServerResponse<ProductData>) => this.data = response?.data?.products,
    error: err => this.errorMessage = err
  });
```